# Doctrine mapping file error Foreign Key Silex

Tags: file, doctrine, mapping, silex

I'm currently learning Silex and I have problems understanding
how to manage foreign keys with Doctrine.

I have an error with the mapping file: *Invalid mapping file*.

Also I found that link, that helped me: [link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html)

Here is my database:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OFSJ.png)

And here is the mapping file for the Post

```
BLOG\Models\Post:


type: entity
  table: posts

  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: auto

  fields:
    title:
      type: string
      length: 255
      column: title
      nullable: false
    date:
      type: datetime
      column: date
      nullable: false
    content:
      type: text
      length: 65535
      column: content
      nullable: false
   manyToOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: User
      mappedBy: Use_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer thanks to this [link](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html?highlight=foreign%20key), I had to change my code for the manyToOne part

```
  manyToOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: User
      joinColumn:
        name: Use_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```